# Nested model forms (accepts_nested_attributes_for) in Rails 4.2.0: subfields not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.2

I am having trouble getting a nested form to work in rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.2.0. I went back and tried to follow [the Railscast from 2010](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast), but even following that example my subfields aren't showing up. What am I doing wrong? Is there a new best practice for nested forms now?

views/surveys/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
    ...
    <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= builder.label :content, 'Question' %><br>
          <%= builder.text_area :content, rows: 3 %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

controllers/survey_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times { @survey.questions.build }
  end
  ...
  private
    ...
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes:[:content])
    end
end
```

models/questions.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  survey_id  :integer
#  content    :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

models/surveys.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: surveys
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

I'm guessing that this is something simple, but I've spent too much time now trying to figure it out. Does anyone know why my fields aren't showing up?

---

**Solution:**

I forgot to render the subfields (<% instead of <%=). The correct text in _form.rb should be:

```
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= builder.label :content, 'Question' %><br>
          <%= builder.text_area :content, rows: 3 %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `<%=` on your `fields_for`

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :content, 'Question' %><br>
      <%= builder.text_area :content, rows: 3 %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I knew it had to be a simple thing I was missing. I'll accept this answer when the site lets me.